# Is there a F# tool / library to visualize values as graphs (like Haskell's vacuum)?

Tags: haskell, f#, visualization

Is there a tool / library like Haskell's [`vacuum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum) for F# to visualize values as graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no F#-specific tool similar to Haskell's [vacuum](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum).

If you're using F# Interactive, [fseye](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/) is worth to explore. It illustrates values in FSI sessions by an object tree inspector  which is convenient for debugging.

To profile F# applications, you may want to look at [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273). The tool does visualize memory allocation, garbage collection and states of the heap. Unfortunately it is not F#-specific, so some indications aren't easy to interprete.

Comment: FsEye 2 (beta series) also features a plugin architecture facilitating alternative visualizations (e.g. the included PropertyGrid-based plugin): http://code.google.com/p/fseye/wiki/FsEye2Beta